# finding the vector function

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $R(t)$ be a vector function such that
$R(0) = \langle0, 5, 3\rangle$,
$R^\prime(0) = \langle1, 0, −2\rangle$, and
$R^{\prime\prime}(0) = \langle3, 4, −8\rangle$.

Find:
i. a vector equation of the tangent line to the graph of $R$ at $t = 0$
now i know that the tangent line is $L = R(0) + tR^\prime(0)$
so the answer would be $\langle t, 5, 3-2t \rangle$.

ii. $h^\prime(0)$ where $h(t) =\Vert R(t)\Vert^2$
i don't know where to get $R(t)$?? am i allowed to use the vector function for the tangent line???

Answer (score 1):

You do not need $R(t)$ to compute $h'(0)$, just recall that $h(t) = \|R(t)\|^2 = \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<R(t), R(t)>$ has the derivative 
$$ h'(t) = \<R'(t), R(t)> + \<R(t), R'(t)> = 2\<R'(t), R(t)> $$
by the product rule, hence 
$$ h'(0) = 2\<R'(0), R(0)>, $$
which can be computed from the given data.

Comment: wait so would the final answer be <(2,0,-4),(0,10,6)>???

Comment: As $2\left<R'(0), R(0)\right> = 2\left<(1,0,-2),(0,5,3)\right> = 2 \cdot (-6) = -12$, no. Just multiply one factor by two, not both, in this way you multiplied the product by four, instead of two.

Comment: additional question: Find (R o g)'(-1) where g=2sinh(4t+4)
now i know i need the vector function for R(t) this time but how do i get it??